# Should I use specific mimeTypes when using 'utf-8' will render static files correctly?

Tags: node.js, mime-types

In my node router, I have some code that is a catch all for static files. I'm wondering if there is any advantage to being more specific with the mimeType when simply specifying utf-8 will do?

```js
module.exports = function router (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/messages' && req.method === 'GET') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(db.msgs));
  } else if (req.url === '/messages' && req.method === 'POST') {
    db.msgs.push(req.body); //req.body is already JSON
    res.end();
  } else {
    //catchall for static files
    if (req.url === '/') req.url = '/index.html';
    if (req.url.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
      const filePath = clientPath + req.url;
      fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          res.statusCode = 500;
          res.end();
        } else {
          let ext;
          //all file types work can be encoded as utf-8, but if you wish to be more explicit, you can use mimeTypes...
          if (req.url.match(/js/)) ext = 'application/javascript';
          if (req.url.match(/css/)) ext = 'text/css';
          if (req.url.match(/html/)) ext = 'text/html';
          if (!ext) ext = 'utf-8';
          res.end(data, ext);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is, that MIME types are invalid parameters for `res.end`, so it defaults to `utf-8` in all cases anyways.

The correct way to send the MIME type along is the HTTP header [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

And there is no benefit of MIME types over encoding, they're separate things:

The encoding determines how the text, that you see in your editor, is transformed into the binary representation that is sent to the client.

The MIME type tells the client how to interpret the decoded text data, i.e. whether is to be used as JavaScript or CSS.

A `Content-Type` header for HTML files usually looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

---

In many cases the MIME type is just a convinient helper to safe the client some time trying to guess what the data is. E.g. for textual content you can iterate through multiple parsers and see which one works but with a specified MIME type, you know which one to use.